# React Native app restarts while on background

Tags: android, ios, react-native, location

I updated my react native app to RN 0.61.2 from RN 0.59 few weeks ago, and a while after that, reading that thread: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26696 made me upgrade to 0.61.5.

Ever since the first update (to 0.61.2), my app keep **restarting while on background** .

I have a background location tracking, that is working well, and I can see log in app of location calls going through. But then without no crash report (sentry), and while app is still in background, the app goes back to splash screen.

This happens when there is no internet connection, but not on the first call. only after about 10 calls of location updates to server the app restarts.

So far I tested it only on iOS, but it might also happen on Android devices.

Have been fighting with this for weeks...

Need help desperately

Would appreciate any advice

Comment: Hate to hear your frustration here. Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: same issue , any fix in it ?

Comment: I believe it happens to me because of the location in background. didn't find a solution yet. was hoping to work on it again next month :)